# Trigger lightbox functionality on button click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I've searched all over and I'm unable to get this to work. I've got a button which I want to use as the main control to load up a lightbox image.

Here is my HTML

```
<li class="span1"> 
      <a href="https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3760/18492500814_4597807b9e_b.jpg" title="FLAG4_km003" class=" thumbnail" target="_blank" data-lightbox="lightbox">
       <img alt="FLAG4_km003" src="https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3760/18492500814_4597807b9e_z.jpg">
      </a>

 <div class="hover-box">
     <p>Title</p>
     <button class="view box-button">Zoom</button>
     <button class="request box-button">Request</button>
 </div>
 </li>
```

As you can see the required lightbox link is in place but I want to trigger the click of it when a user clicks on the 'Zoom' button.

Here is my jQuery which currently isn't working:

```
$(document).on('click', '.view', function(){ 
    $(this).closest("li.span1 a").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest` doesn't work like that. It selects the first/closest matching parent of the element. You should at first select the closest `li` element and then select the child/descendant `a` element.

```
$(this).closest("li.span1").children('a').click();
```

You could also use the `parent` and `siblings` methods for selecting the target element:

```
$(this).parent("div.hover-box").siblings('a.thumbnail').click();
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your help. No dice however, doesn't work. The `a.thumbnail` isn't responding to being clicked.

Comment: @WebDevDanno You are welcome. That's a different problem. `console.log` the returned collection and it should show the selected `a` element. Add a click listener for the target `a` element and you should see the `click` handler is executed.